# Server Sent Event Spring Webflux return event name in response from rest controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I am using SSE with reactor Flux for capturing linux system metrics and publishing to browser(javascript eventsource).

Currently, the problem is not able to send specific data to specific client. After going through multiple SO posts, it is told to use event listener in the eventsource and response from server should have **event** as key in the response.

Since, I am returning an object from the server, is it enough to have **event** as one of the key in the response json which will be identified by the eventsource.

Setting an unique number in the client side, which will be return in the **event** key in the json response.

Thanks for the help !

**Javascript:**

```
jsonStreamObjectHeap.addEventListener("197e08e-f9a4-4e6e-9a04-220ade08a8f4",function(e){
        $.each(message, function(index, value) {
           /*some operation*/
        });
        }
```

**Response From Rest Controller:**

```
{
   "event":"197e08e-f9a4-4e6e-9a04-220ade08a8f4",
   "data":"2048"
}
```

**Rest Controller Code:**

```
 Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        interval.subscribe((i) -> testStreamList.forEach(testStream -> {
            try {
                generateTestStream(testStream, UUID);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));
 Flux<List<TestStream>> transactionFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> testStreamList));
 return Flux.zip(interval, transactionFlux).map(Tuple2::getT2);
```

Comment: The subscriber is the calling client, your application is a publisher, so don't subscribe in the publisher. So remove the "subscribe". And then second, what is `generateTestStream` and `testStramList`. The code is hard to follow, am i correct to assume that all you want to do is to return one object from your `testStreamList` at a given interval (1 sec). And this object needs to be an SSE? If that is correct, this is a messy way of writing it, and the way you have written it is blocking too.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf You are correct. Can you please advise, how can I proceed ? or any link/help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEvent` which can be plugged into your Flux response from the rest controller.

```
  Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));    
  Flux<HeapStat> transactionFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> heapStat));

  /*Bulding ServerSentEvent to from the tuple*/

  return Flux.zip(interval, transactionFlux).map(tuple->
           ServerSentEvent.<HeapStat>builder().event(jsessionId).data(tuple.getT2()).build()
                );
```

You can prepare response exactly like `SSEEmmiter`with custom event name, Last-Event-ID

Comment: Any way to send an error instead of an event in the Flux.zip?